# Phpstan doctrine database connection error

Tags: database, docker, doctrine, phpstan

I'm using doctrine in a project (not symfony). In this project I also use phpstan, i installed both `phpstan/phpstan-doctrine` and `phpstan/extension-installer`.
My phpstan.neon is like this:

```yaml
parameters:
    level: 8
    paths:
        - src/
    doctrine:
        objectManagerLoader: tests/object-manager.php
```

Inside  tests/object-manager.php it return the result of a call to a function that return the entity manager.

Here is the code that create the entity manager

```php
$database_url = $_ENV['DATABASE_URL'];
$isDevMode = $this->isDevMode();
$proxyDir = null;
$cache = null;
$useSimpleAnnotationReader = false;

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    [$this->getProjectDirectory() . '/src'],
    $isDevMode,
    $proxyDir,
    $cache,
    $useSimpleAnnotationReader
);


// database configuration parameters
$conn = [
    'url' => $database_url,
];

// obtaining the entity manager
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

When i run `vendor/bin/phpstan analyze` i get this error:

```
Internal error: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres_db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

This appear because i'm using docker and my database url is `postgres://user:password@postgres_db/database` `postgres_db` is the name of my database container so the hostname is known inside the docker container.

When i run phpstan inside the container i do not have the error.

**So is there a way to run phpstan outside docker ? Because i'm pretty sure that when i'll push my code the github workflow will fail because of this**

**Do phpstan need to try to reach the database ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on the github of phpstan-doctrine and i had an [answer by @jlherren](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan-doctrine/issues/292#issuecomment-1046078185) that explained :

> The problem is that Doctrine needs to know what version of the DB server it is working with in order to instantiate the correct AbstractPlatform implementation, of which there are several available for the same DB vendor (e.g. PostgreSQL94Platform or PostgreSQL100Platform for postgres, and similarly for other DB drivers). To auto-detect this information, it will simply connect to the DB and query the version.

I just changed my database url from:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@database_ip/database
```

To:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@database_ip/database?serverVersion=14.2
```